# Connecting to Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

We are trying to build a logging tool where we'll be able to connect to the specific azure VM, based on subscription ID and Deployment ID, so that we'll be able to process different VM usage counters. The tool that we are trying to build is a limited version of Cerebrata's Azure Diagnostic Manager. So any pointers regarding how to connect to the azure VM's would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to know how to RDP to a VM or do you need to programatically connect via an API?

Comment: We know how to RDP to a VM using management portal. What we want is to connect to the VM through code i.e via some available API and collect log data directly from the VM

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you just use the Diagnostics monitor to transfer the required counters/logs/etc. to Azure storage and read it from there.